# Android API Key for Android Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm Working on Android Map.When i want to generate the API key V2 .There is no option like this to enable API key v2.[You can see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHxc2.png)

Please guide me to put map in my application.please ignore mistakes in question.

Comment: its already enabled in that pic

Comment: i am sharing tutorial image.in my case i cannot find this on google console

Answer (score 0):

Generate an api key by going through credentials tab.
There google will ask your application package name and SHA1 finger print key.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a project in google dev console. After that generate a sha1 key and put the key in this project. Here see official documentation. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#if-you-are-using-the-standard-google-maps-android-api

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a project on developer console dashboard.
Then you need a  sha1 key for this -

Run the following command on cmd to get your sha1: `keytool -v -list -keystore "<debug.keystore path>` and press “enter” when a password asked.

Then copy and keep SHA1 for later use. For my case it is (3C:64:03:7B:0E:F7:E5:71:0D:10:9D:62:4C:03:8C:F2:4E:AD:B8:94)
- Get the key for android apps.

1. You need to have a gmail account.
2. Create Google APIs project from https://code.google.com/apis/console address.
3. From services, Turn “Google Maps Android API v2” to ON.
4. From API Access, create new Android Key.
5. Paste SHA1 and your package name <SHA1>;<package name> for example at my case it is (3C:64:03:7B:0E:F7:E5:71:0D:10:9D:62:4C:03:8C:F2:4E:AD:B8:94;info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2)
6. Copy generated API for later use, for my case it is AIzaSyDciL7-T3BphxGv2q-A77vNrcyJQ_sTrgI

for more detail go through with this doc. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this image.Click on "Google Maps Android API" then click on "Enable".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a map activity in android studio.there is a file called google_maps_api.xml in that file there is a link to gerenerate and enable API.So that put that link on your browser and get the key. and paste it in google_maps_api.xml at required space..[image]

By doing this you will get apiv2 access